# Testing/Debugging Shell Extension & Regasm & explorer.exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows, com

I successfully created a shell extension (A context menu handler to be exact) in C# using .NET 4.0. I used Regasm to register the extension, and again Regasm to unregister the extension. The whole process works wonderfully.

I am having one problem though: explorer.exe won't let go of my DLL after testing. I can't delete it, and I can't do another build without VS complaining. The only thing I've been able to do to release the DLL is restart explorer.exe. So that's my question: How do I test as I go along without going through that whole process each time?

I'd also appreciate any tips on speeding up the testing/debugging process.

Edit: I found the Register for COM Interop option in my project properties. It does speed up the debugging process, but I'm still left with the explorer.exe issue.

Edit 2: I did end creating a batch file to kill and then restart explorer.exe, and used that in my pre-build event. However even though I used to "start" command to run the tasks in the background, Visual Studio would freeze indefinitely during the build process. I ended up using this tool http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/ to completely run the commands in the background.

Comment: Just as a thought, you can safely kill/restart explorer.exe from the process manager without logging out. It's relatively quick and painless.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks. That's what I'm doing. Yeah, it works.. But I like to build and test a lot as I'm going, so it's kind of a pain.

Comment: write a batch file (Powershell?) to stop and restart explorer.exe. Add to pre-build step.

Comment: @Mitch, So the consensus here is restarting explorer.exe between builds is just the price one pays when writing extensions?

Comment: @mellowsoon: I don't know of a way around this, but someone might....

Comment: @mellowsoon: The only way around this I can think of would be if explorer.exe explicitly unloaded the DLL. If it doesn't do that automatically, then you're pretty much screwed I think. Unfortunate, but there you have it.

Comment: Killing explorer.exe seems to be the way to go. The good news is the "reboot" process now only takes a few seconds. It seems it got faster the more I did it.

Comment: Killing and restarted explorer.exe is the only way.

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is here. All the comments are correct, but no one actually answered the question. So I have no way of giving the point to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did end creating a batch file to kill and then restart explorer.exe, and used that in my pre-build event. However even though I used to "start" command to run the tasks in the background, Visual Studio would freeze indefinitely during the build process. I ended up using this tool http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/ to completely run the commands in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have another suggestion: You could use [Unlocker](http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/) to unlock the DLL. After that, you should be able to compile again.
According to the website, Unlocker even features a command line tool, so you could integrate it into your build process.

Comment: I actually tried this first. Unlocker is a tool that's near and dear to me haha Sadly it didn't work. The best it could do was give the option to delete the dll on the next reboot.